# oracle ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

When using a cursor to bulk collect results in a sys.odcivarchar2list i get this error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind
My loop executes for many times with no error but only for a specific table which i collect all data into the varchar2 list i am getting this error. I used this code:

```
declare
  filehandle1 utl_file.file_type;
  myquery varchar2(4000) := 'select column1 ||''~''|| column2 from mytable';
  mycursor sys_refcursor;
  myresults sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  filehandle1 := utl_file.fopen ('D42', 'mydata', 'w');
  open mycursor for myquery; 
  loop
   fetch mycursor bulk collect into myresults;
if myresults.count>0 Then
    for idx in myresults.first..myresults.last loop
      utl_file.put_line(filehandle1, myresults(idx));
    end loop;
End if;
    exit when mycursor%notfound;
  end loop;
  close mycursor;
  utl_file.fclose(filehandle1);
end;
```

This returns results from more than 100 tables but only 1 of the tables is crashing. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Possibly because of a `clob` column, as discussed on the previous question. Would be interested to see that confirmed though.

Comment: @Alex.. If i convert the clob to char and write the results to the file.. then how will sqlloader will try to input the data since you mentioned correctly that it might need special treatment?

Comment: I believe you'd need to write each `clob` to a separate file to everything else, which SQL*Loader can then reference; as shown in the [artice I linked to](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader.php) before. Not something I've tried though.

Comment: @alex.. I looked the article you provided above.. I want to ask you "the filename columns in the datafile are marked as FILLERs, so they are not loaded into the table, but they are used in the LOBFILE definition to identify the location of the LOB information." Do i really need these column? I am going to write everything in the data file and in the control file for loader i am going to add clob_content LOBFILE TERMINATED BY EOF because when ivoking the loader i am giving the for control and data through parameters from the command. Is the above statement for the column definition correct?

Comment: Every LOB value has to be in its *own* file. If your table has 100 rows you'll have 100 LOB files, and the rest of the data in the file you already create, with each row in that file pointing to the row-specific LOB file name. So you do have to have that LOB filename in the data file; but the relevant LOB is loaded in its place.

Comment: So i will have to query the table first to see how many clob files i will need and then pass this as a parameter back to linux and do a for loop and create as many files i will need and write in each file every row of the table. Afterwards for the loading i will again have to do sth with linux to count how many clob files i have and do a for loop and invoke sqlloader so many files inside a for loop

Comment: Is is possible to get variable from the plsql block back to linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write each CLOB value out into a separate file, and include that file name as part of the main data record. Something like this:

```
declare
  data_file utl_file.file_type;
  clob_file utl_file.file_type;
  buffer varchar2(32767);
  position pls_integer;
  chars pls_integer;

  myquery varchar2(4000) := 'select column1 ||''~''|| column3, '
    || '''column2_'' || rownum, column2 from mytable';
  mycursor sys_refcursor;
  myresult varchar2(4000);
  myfilename varchar2(120);
  myclob clob;
begin
  data_file := utl_file.fopen ('D42', 'mydata', 'w');
  open mycursor for myquery; 
  loop
    fetch mycursor into myresult, myfilename, myclob;
    exit when mycursor%notfound;
    if myclob is not null and dbms_lob.getlength(myclob) > 0 then
      myresult := myresult ||'~'|| myfilename;
      clob_file := utl_file.fopen ('D42', myfilename, 'w', 32767);
      position := 1;
      chars := 32767;
      while position < dbms_lob.getlength(myclob) loop
        dbms_lob.read(myclob, chars, position, buffer);
        utl_file.put(clob_file, buffer);
        utl_file.fflush(clob_file);
        position := position + chars;
      end loop;
      utl_file.fclose(clob_file);
    end if;
    utl_file.put_line(data_file, myresult);
  end loop;
  close mycursor;
  utl_file.fclose(data_file);
end;
/
```

There is one `data_file` which has all the non-CLOB data, including the name of the individual file you write that row's CLOB to. The filename can be anything as long as it's unique; I've used `rownum` but you can use the row's primary key ID if it has one, for example.

With a dummy table created as:

```
create table mytable (column1 number, column2 clob, column3 varchar2(10));
insert into mytable (column1, column2, column3) values (1, null, 'First');
insert into mytable (column1, column2, column3) values (2, 'Second CLOB', 'Second');
insert into mytable (column1, column2, column3) values (3, 'Third CLOB', 'Third');
```

.. this creates `mydata` containing:

```
1~First
2~Second~column2_2
3~Third~column2_3
```

and files `column2_2` and `column2_3` with the corresponding CLOB values.

Then if I run SQL*Loader with that data file and the CLOB files available, and control file:

```
load data
characterset UTF8
truncate
into table mytable2
fields terminated by "~"
trailing nullcols
(
  column1 char(10),
  column3 char(10),
  clob_filename filler char(120),
  column2 lobfile(clob_filename) terminated by EOF
)
```

... the new table is populated as:

```
select * from mytable2;

   COLUMN1 COLUMN2                        COLUMN3  
---------- ------------------------------ ----------
         1                                First      
         2 Second CLOB                    Second
         3 Third CLOB                     Third
```

(I still think you should be doing this with the built-in tools, data pump or just copying data internally between two schemas, as discussed on previous questions...)

Comment: Thank you very much alex for your help and support. That is very helpful my only concern now after all this is what you are stating at the end. Perhaps it will be more efficient to use the data pump utility for this table with the clob column and just  export and import the data. But i can tell you that using the sqlloader though gave me the chance to enrich my knowledge more on cursor functions and writing to files including shell scripts of linux

Comment: On this one maybe i will draw the line and use the data pump because what happens in the case when you have to export thousands of rows that have clob column.. will end up in the end writing thousands of files and then importing thousands of files. So as you are suggesting data pump will be more effective on this table

Answer (score 2):

I received this EXACT Error however it was due to my storing the result that was returned by a Ref Cursor into a field in a collection that was too small to store the value.  The field was defined as a VARCHAR2(25 CHAR) however I was attempting to store more than 25 characters in this field.

Took a bit to dissect.  The key was narrowing down exactly where the error was occurring and it was right as the Ref Cursor was FETCHING the data INTO my collection.

`FETCH rc BULK COLLECT INTO [collection]`

Hope this helps somebody.